# For loop only printing 1st value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a site for the values of cases but when I run the program it only returns 1 value. ['203,377'], How do I get the other values to return

```
page = requests.get("https://www.theguardian.com/world/ng-interactive/2020/apr/13/coronavirus-map-us-latest-covid-19-cases-state-by-state")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
state_table = soup.find(id='co-table-container')
item2 = state_table.find_all(class_='co-table')
case2 = [ c2.find(class_='co-td-cases').get_text() for c2 in item2]
print(case2)
```

Comment: `item2` is a result set with only 1 value. The for loop can only loop over that one item. Everything is ok

Comment: You seem to have two values.  Please update with a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I changed

```
item2 = state_table.find(class_='co-table')
case2 = [ c2.get_text() for c2 in item2.find_all(class_='co-td-cases')]
print(case2)
```

There is just a single `class_='co-table'`, that has several `class_='co-td-cases'`, so the list comprehension is modified accordingly.

Comment: Try this, try that, ... Maybe you want to explain a) what you changed and b) why you changed it (what makes the difference)

Comment: @ThomasWeller there it is...